# How to automatically delete backed up photos in Android 10?

Tags: automation, google-photos

I'm trying to figure out a way to detect when a photo has been backed up from my device so I can automatically delete it.  I was reading that there was a feature to do this already, but when I found [the help page](https://support.google.com/files/answer/10862356?hl=en) it said it is only available on Pixel devices running Android S (which appears to be version 12).   I am not able to meet these conditions, so what alternative method can I use to automate the process of detecting when a photo is uploaded?

Update:
To make it clear what I'm trying to do, suppose that I fill up my storage with images and videos.  In `Settings > Storage` I see an option `Smart Storage` which is on.  Under this it says "When storage is almost full, remove backed up photos and videos.  You can still find them in Google Photos."  But what I observe is that after the photos and videos are backed up, they remain on the device and are not removed as this text is suggested they should be.  It's important to me that this happen in an automated manner. My assumption from reading the above mentioned help page is a reason this isn't happening could be because it's not supported on my device (which is strange since it appears to offer it to me.)

Comment: Open Photos, click your personal icon (top right), click Free Up Space?

Comment: @JimClark Please see my update

Comment: Hi @Michael. I don't have A12. I am not a developer. When you look at the pictures on your phone (after having them backed up to Photos) are they smaller in size than the original photos? If you don't have the photos on your device, then to view them you will need a wifi connection or data connection to see them on Photos. I thought Photos only keeps smaller files on the phone to view them on the phone's smaller screen, while the original photo is saved on-line. You may want to download your pictures to your PC from Google, there is a process, https://takeout.google.com

Comment: Go to your file manager, internal storage, DCIM, camera. 
Are the photos still there or have they been cleared out?

Comment: @JimClark Thanks for your response.  So here is what I see right now.  The files are still there in the DCIM/Camera folder. When I got to Settings > Storage it says I am using 128GB/128GB (100%) although it's actually rounding up as I have around 300MB free.   In Google Photos it says there is the option to "Free Up Space" of 1.66GB which is also correct in the size of it but what I am trying to figure out is why Smart Storage isn't deleting it automatically.

Comment: Every now and then, I used to manually go to Photos, Settings, and manually hit Free Up Space. Now I have photos go to an SD card and manage my photos myself. In Step 1 of the following, it indicates only certain phones satisfies the requirements... Anyway maybe this page will help. https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/automatically-delete-pictures-videos-youve-backed-up-google-photos-0251755/

Comment: Go to Photos, Backup and Sync, hit the question mark, then troubleshoot issues with auto backup. They mention battery optimization as a reason it may not work.

Comment: @JimClark I just read an article which suggests that even with this "feature" turned on, it still waits 30 days to actually delete.  Which makes it useless for me.